# Setting multiple choices using jquery chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen's plugin to select multiple items from data loaded from a database. This is saved, and then I might want to load those choices again (the entire form, really) to edit it, and save changes.

I can successfully read the various choices from the select component like so:

```
$("#meet_participants").chosen().val();
```

However If I want to set the multiple choices I'm trying this test case:

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Participantes</label><br>
    <b>
    <select data-placeholder="Ingrese los nombres" class="chosen-select form-control" style="width:60%" multiple id="meet_participants">
    <!--Filled with all db users.-->
    <option>hola</option>
    <option>mundo</option>
    <option>cruel</option>
    <option>como</option>
    <option>estas</option>
    </select>
    </b>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><b>Tareas pendientes</b></button>
  </div> <!--formgroup-->
</div> <!--row-->
```

The after that I do (as per the example)

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/plugins/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var config = {
'.chosen-select'           : {},
'.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
'.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
  }
  for (var selector in config) {
$(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
  }
</script>


<script>
  fillMemoForm();
  $("#meet_participants").chosen().val(["hola", "mundo", "cruel"]);
</script>
```

Only the last line is important, however I pasted everything just in case. As I understand this should have set the selected values to these three items, but it didn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

A better solution for this instead of destroying and re-creating dom element would be

```
$('#meet_participants').val(["hola","mundo","cruel"]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Answer (score 2):

Val in chosen plugin does not refresh the control. Call destroy, like this instead

```
$('#meet_participants').chosen('destroy').val(["hola","mundo","cruel"]).chosen();
```

```js
$('#meet_participants').chosen();

$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#meet_participants').chosen('destroy').val(["hola", "mundo", "cruel"]).chosen();
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
  $('#meet_participants').chosen('destroy').val(["estas", "como"]).chosen();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select data-placeholder="Ingrese los nombres" class="chosen-select form-control" multiple id="meet_participants" style="width:50%">
      <option>hola</option>
      <option>mundo</option>
      <option>cruel</option>
      <option>como</option>
      <option>estas</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn">set ["hola", "mundo", "cruel"]</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button id="btn2" class="btn">set ["estas", "como"]</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting comma separated value to be updated in chosen multiple select, first convert it into an array then trigger the update for that array.

```
var meet_participants = "hola,mundo,cruel";  
var array = meet_participants.split(',');
$('#meet_participants').val(array).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Voilà !